# difference in classloading between Java and Scala

Tags: java, scala

Is classloading would be the same between java and scala or it is handled differently in scala

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scala does not do anything special with class loading at all.  Once Scala code is compiled to byte code it looks and behaves as if the source had been Java.

Comment: There has been some discussion about providing backward compatibility by doing classloader tricks. So, while this is true right now, it might not hold true in the future.